# How to creata an array of JEditorPane

Tags: arrays, jeditorpane

I want to create an array of JEditorPane depending on the size of a String array.
Is there a possibility to create an array of JEditorPane? If yes, how?

Here is an example:

```
String [] elements = {"0","1","2","3","4"};
JEditorPane ePane [] = new JEditorPane[5];
```

I want to to put each String element into the certain JEditPane, i.e

```
JEditorPane[0].setText(elements[0]);
```

etc. But I get a nullpointerexception when run I run.

Comment: Just as you would create an array of anyything else? With JEditorPane[] jeparray = new JEditorPane[stringArray.length];? What exactly do you ant to do and why exactly do you think it doesnt work the same as with any other object/type?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that Java initializes a new array with the default value for the given type. In this case it is `null`, because the `JEditorPane` inherits from `Object`.

You cannot call a method on `null` - that is where the `NullPointerException` comes from.

**The solution:** make a loop in which you initialize the `JEditorPane`-objects in the array.

Then you can do `JEditorPane[0].setText(elements[0]);`

Comment: @user3300710 what did you do?